# How do I create a script to move all the log files for a particular month to a Folder?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, grep

I have some log files in an archive folder. I need to pull out some user information from the log file and copy those files to a folder. Can anyone tell me how to automate this ?.

Manual:

```
   cd /archive
   zgrep -c 'user' *05-01-2017* | grep -v ":0"
```

If logs exists, move those logs to a folder.

Could anyone tell me how can I create a script to automate this. I need to move files for a particular user for 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

No need for script: the `find` command will suffice

```
# find $PATH_TO_LOGS_DIR -type f -mtime $RELEVANT_DATE -exec mv {} $TARGET_DIR \;
```